# html content loaded by ajax functions

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Well, this topic has been discussed (a lot), and I used all the answers to write my own code, but... I can't make it work.

I have different thumbnails which lead to .html pages that I am trying to load in a div (in my main page) by using ajax functions. The div which will contain the content is 'galerie-container' (original, eh ?) and appears on click on the thumbnails (via jquery, too)

So far, I got this code (in document.ready() ) :

```
$(".galerie-thumbnails a").click(function(){

    if (trigger == 0) {

        $("#galerie-container, .galerie-thumbnails-wrap:visible .galerie-div").slideDown("slow");
        $("#galerie .content").animate({"top": "-=235px"}, "slow");
        $(".next, .prev").hide();
        $(".galerie-thumbnails a").css({"opacity": "0.2"}).click(function(){ return false;
        });             
        trigger = 1;

        // ***** loading pages in #galerie-content ******

        url = $(this).attr("href");
        getContent(url);

        $(this).blur();
        return false;
        } 

    else {

        $("#galerie-container, .galerie-thumbnails-wrap:visible .galerie-div").slideUp("slow");
        $("#galerie .content").animate({"top": "+=235px"}, "slow");
        $(".next, .prev").delay(600).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".galerie-thumbnails a").css({"opacity": "1"});
        trigger = 0;
        $('#galerie-content').text('bye');
        return false;
        }
    });

 function getContent(url) {
        $.ajax({
        url: url+"ajax.html",
        dataType: "html",
        //if it worked
        success: function(html) {
            $("#galerie-content").html(html).fadeIn();
        }
        });
}
```

I also tried something with :

```
var page = $(this).attr('href');    
$('#galerie-content').load('galerie/' + page + '.html');
```

but it doesn't work either. I just can't load the page, nothing happens when the container appears.

As some people asked, my website is online in a free web hosting service. And when I try to click on my thumbnails with the debugger on, I have the following error :
**'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error404.000webhost.com/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access. '**

However, all of my files are under the same domain and I can access to the individual file from the URL bar, and I have also change my .htaccess file (with :

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

)

Do you have any ideas ? I hope you have all the information needed.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: what error is shown in the browser console(press `F12`)

Comment: Are you using any web server? You have to make a http request in order to work with Jquery ajax, you can't load local file.

Comment: @ Nishan Senevirathna : Yes, actually I use a free web hosting.
@ suhail : I have 4 errors all due to my web hosting (for instance : GET http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT )

Comment: When I had a problem with ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT it was due to an ad blocker extension.